# SFML: Unable to run code because of soundbuffer error

Tags: visual-studio-code, sfml

I came across a problem that wouldn't let me play sounds on SFML. Whenever I call the `sf::SoundBuffer buffer;` object, the code would break and spit out an error.

I either think its a problem inside the makefile. Other than that, I'm completely lost in what to do

Sample of makefile:

```
all: compile link

compile:
    g++ -I src/include -c main.cpp
link:
    g++ main.o -o Sorter -L src/lib -l sfml-audio -l sfml-graphics -l sfml-window -l sfml-system
```

[Picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCyxM.png)

Comment: The error tells you exactly what is wring. Do you have the mentioned dll file in the application directory?

Comment: No, none that I could see